# output in query ( ColdFusion )

Tags: database, coldfusion

I wonder if it is possible to put the output data in a query, for example i have a query:

```
<cfquery name="get_search_results" datasource="#dsn3#">SELECT * FROM SERVICE_GUARANTY_NEW WHERE SERIAL_NO = #get_service.PRO_SERIAL_NO#</cfquery>
```

and output:

```
<cfoutput query="get_service">#get_service.PRO_SERIAL_NO#</cfoutput>
```

as u can see i inserted output in a query, and it doesnt work, how do i put it in a right way? thx for help!

just in case the query of the get_service output:

```
<cfquery name="get_service" datasource="#dsn3#">
    SELECT * FROM SERVICE WHERE SERVICE_ID = #attributes.action_id#
</cfquery>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: you have to use cfqueryPARAM for this. If Serial_NO datatype is Varchar it will look something like this:

```
<cfquery name = "get_search_results" dataSource = "#dsn3#">
    SELECT * 
    FROM SERVICE_GUARANTY_NEW
    WHERE SERIAL_NO = <cfqueryPARAM value = "#get_service.PRO_SERIAL_NO#"
    CFSQLType = 'CF_SQL_VARCHAR'> 
</cfquery>
```

But I think it's better to merge the two sql queries "get_search_result" and "get_service" into one sql:

```
SELECT *
FROM SERVICE_GUARANTY_NEW
WHERE SERIAL_NO IN (
  SELECT PRO_SERIAL_NO 
  FROM SERVICE 
  WHERE SERVICE_ID = #attributes.action_id#
)
```

Using subquery is faster than problematical reusing result from one query in a new query.

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to try something like this:

```
<cfquery name="get_service" datasource="#dsn3#">
    SELECT #carrythroughVar# as carryThroughVar, * FROM SERVICE WHERE SERVICE_ID = #attributes.action_id#
</cfquery>
```

similar to the way you can do `select 1`

this is untested.

hth

Comment: thank you, but actually im trying to insert the code of output to a get_search_results query, and what does carrythroughvar mean?

Comment: well, i think query results are not changeable. so if you really need to insert something into the results, you should set up a loop that copies each record of the query into a struct while adding your data. then you'll loop over the struct instead of the query. don't worry about carrythroughvar, now, that was my name for whatever data you wanted to put in the query and have it come out in the results. but i think using a struct-copy of the results is what you want now.